# Search string in all varchar2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table which contains `number` and `varchar2` data type columns.

myTable

```
project_id - number
project_ldr - number 
project_text1 - varchar2
project_text2 - varchar2
project_text3 - varchar2
project_text4 - varchar2
project_text5 - varchar2
project_text6 - varchar2
project_text7 - varchar2
```

I would like to search for a string in all the varchar2 columns and fetch the rows from table.

Currently I have the following sql for getting row if it matches string impl

```
select * from myTable where lower(project_text1) like lower('%impl%') or 
lower(project_text2) like lower('%impl%')... (all other varchar2 columns)
```

I would like to are there any better ways to achieve the results.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer implementing **Full Text Search(FTS)** in such scenarios.
google for full text search.
you will get faster result with FTS than your current implementation

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple:

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
 WHERE lower (project_text1 || project_text2 || project_text3 ||
              project_text4 || project_text5 || project_text6 ||
              project_text7) LIKE lower('%impl%');
```